# Integral $\int_0^1\ln^2(t)\psi^8(-t)dt=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, definite-integrals, theta-functions

I was working on the following Integral:

$$I=\int_0^1\ln^2(t)\psi^8(-t)dt=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)$$

Where,
$$\psi(q)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}q^{n(2n+1)}$$
is a Ramanujan Theta Function.

Now it is well known that,
$$q\psi^8(q)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^3\left[\frac{q^n}{1-q^{2n}}\right]$$

Using this we have,

$$I=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nn^3\int_0^1\ln^2(t)\frac{t^{n-1}}{1-t^{2n}}dt$$

And,
$$\int_0^1\ln^2(t)\frac{t^{n-1}}{1-t^{2n}}dt=\frac{2}{n^3}\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2r+1)^3}$$

Therefore,
$$I=-2\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\right)\left(\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+2r)^{3}}\right)$$

Now I am not exactly sure what to do with the Summation on the Left, if we had to assign it a value then we could give using Geometric Series Formula,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Then it's proven that,

$$I=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)$$

I am not sure about that last step as the series switches between $-1$ and $0$.

After rechecking the steps I am confused how this situation arises.

Comment: That is because $\frac{-1}{2}$ is the Cesaro sum of the Grandi Series, and not the actual sum. The normal sum of Grandi series diverges - as you have observed, it oscillates between $-1$ & $0$, but it's Cesaro sum converges.